# Pass member function as parameter to a parent class in a different header

Tags: c++, class, events

Consider two classes. One being EventReceiver in a header file named `events.h` that defines a method Subscribe which takes in a name parameter and some callback function, and a class that derives EventReceiver in a header `entities.h` named Entity, that defines a method OnStart, which must be called on event named `"start"` in the constructor.

**events.h**

```cpp
class EventReceiver
{
public:
    void SubscribeEvent(string name, callback_type callback);
}
```

**entities.h**

```cpp
#include "events.h"

class Entity : public EventReceiver
{
public:
    Entity();
    void OnStart();
}
```

How would I accomplish that? What type should `callback_type` be to accept the OnStart function, since I can't declare it as `void (Entity::*)()` in `EventReceiver` because of a dependency loop, and can't pass a pointer to `OnStart` because its non-static?

Comment: How about [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)? Use together with e.g. [`std::mem_fn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn), [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind), or [lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to go the `std::function` route, it'd probably look something like:

```
// events.h:
using callback_type = std::function<void()>;

// entities.h (the constructor):
Entity() {
    SubscribeEvent("start", [this](){ OnStart(); });
}
```